# Как установить Python 3.5.9 с официального сайта в формате .tgz

Tags: python, установка

Возможно глупый вопрос, но в нигде не могу найти инструкцию. 
Я скачиваю с https://www.python.org/downloads/release/python-359/

архив Python-3.5.9.tgz

Вопрос: Что с этим делать дальше? Как мне собственно Python поставить? :|
[image]

Comment: Устанавливать Linux, распаковывать архив, запускать `./configure`, а потом выполнять `make`.

Comment: Вы уверены, что вам необходима сборка из исходников? Если нет, то скачайте установщик для `windows`. Если да, начните с прочтения `README` файла.

Comment: Мне нужно на Windows.

Comment: На офф сайте только в формате tgz версия 3.5.9

Comment: А почему именно эта версия? Последняя версия это 3.8 (если что).

Comment: `3.5.4` - последняя версия пятой ветки, которая распространяется в виде бинарных установщиков.

Comment: Эникейщик, с 3.8 какие-то проблемы при установке на семерку

Comment: Какие именно проблемы?

Comment: @CoffeeinTime даже если вдруг проблемы, то почему нужно устанавливать 3.5.9, которая даже и не версия на самом деле (см. release notes)?